# Compare number in group in given year to different group in previous year

Tags: r

I have a data frame in the following form (grouped by Year, Subject and Level). There are two „Levels“ and around 25 Subjects (the number varies per year) over 30 years.

Code to reproduce:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L), Subject = c("Englisch", 
"Englisch", "GK", "GK", "Mathematik", "Mathematik", "Englisch", "Englisch", "GK", "GK", "Mathematik", "Mathematik", "Englisch", "Englisch", "GK", "GK", "Mathematik", "Mathematik", "Englisch", 
"Englisch"), Level = c(20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 21L), Students = c(27104L, 24841L, 29945L, 2862L, 29907L, 27802L, 28837L, 26357L, 31815L, 2880L, 31721L, 29115L, 30324L, 28064L, 32924L, 3508L, 32862L, 30862L, 32124L, 29624L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(Year = c(2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L), Subject = c("Englisch", "GK", "Mathematik", "Englisch", "GK", "Mathematik", "Englisch", "GK", "Mathematik", "Englisch"), .rows = structure(list(1:2,     3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) -> rep
```

| Year | Subject | Students | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | English | 100 | 1 |
| 2000 | Maths | 50 | 1 |
| 2000 | ... | ... | ... |
| 2001 | Maths | 30 | 2 |
| 2001 | English | 70 | 2 |

After each year, students usually ascend one level. To find out how many students did not ascend a level I need to calculate `Level 1 Students of English in 2000 - Level 2 Students of English in 2001`

The new data frame should thus look like this:

| Year | Subject | Students | Level | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | English | 100 | 1 | NA |
| 2000 | Maths | 50 | 1 | NA |
| 2000 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2001 | Maths | 30 | 2 | 20 |
| 2001 | English | 70 | 2 | 30 |

I have tried dplyr:lag() but I don't know how to make it work with several groups.

Comment: Please provide data in a useful form. Also, For how many years do you have data, cos you also have to account for students that did not progress from Level 2 to Level 3, meaning they will be still counted as being in Level 2 group. Right?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer that there are two levels and data for 30 years. As most students who do not ascent usually drop out, counting some students twice is not as big a problem. Which form of the data would be more useful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get that with `lag` after `arrange` and `group_by` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Subject, Year, Level) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Difference = lag(Students) - Students)
  #You can also use diff
  #mutate(Difference = c(NA, -diff(Students)))
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me; it just subtracts the students on Level 2 from those on Level 1 in one year.

Comment: @SamVimes Can you provide a reproducible example using `dput` which can be copied easily into R for testing purpose ? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @SamVimes Maybe try the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you - I've included an example. Your solution appears to work if I change it to   `mutate(Difference = lag(Students, 3) - Students)`

Answer (score 0):

We may do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(Subject, Year, Level)][, 
   Difference := shift(Students) - Students), by = Subject]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your command appears to only subtract the number of level 2 students of a given subject in a given year from the level 1 students of the same year. It appears to work if I shift by three rows like so `setDT(Änderung)[order(Subject, Year, Level)][, Difference := shift(Students,3) - (Students), by = Subject]`